# How to avoid showing the title of the category when there is no news related to that category?

Tags: php, mysqli

In the design that I am implemented, is to have an order of each news by their categories.

When there are news related to that category, the results are displayed correctly without any problem

**Example:**

```
 PREMIER LEAGUE
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2

 CUP AMERICA
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 3
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 4
```

My little problem in the code of the query, is that when there is no news for a category, the title of that category is displayed, resulting in the following:

```
PREMIER LEAGUE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2

CUP AMERICA
```

So my question is, how can I avoid showing the category title when there is no news related to that category?

**In order to have, a consequent result:**

```
PREMIER LEAGUE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2

CUP AMERICA
```

## My code

```
$stmtcategory = $con->prepare("SELECT id_category,title_category FROM category WHERE active=?");
$stmtcategory->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";
$stmtcategory->execute();
$stmtcategory->store_result();

if ($stmtcategory->num_rows>0) {
    $stmtcategory->bind_result($id_category, $title_category);
    while ($stmtcategory->fetch()) {
        echo '<div class="date-text">
            <h4>'.$title_category.'</h4>
            <ul>';

        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_one_more_news,cover_page,title,description,detail,url,date_post FROM one_more_news WHERE id_category=? order by id_one_more_news ASC LIMIT 2");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id_category);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id_one_more_news, $cover_page, $title, $description, $detail, $url, $date_post);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';
            }

            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            //echo "<span>There is no news</span>";
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "There is no news";
}
```

## Additional Information

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little change in your code. First, query the news according to the category. Second, check if there is the news or not. If not, don't show the category.

```
$stmtcategory = $con->prepare("SELECT id_category,title_category FROM category WHERE active=?");
$stmtcategory->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";
$stmtcategory->execute();
$stmtcategory->store_result();

if ($stmtcategory->num_rows>0) {
    $stmtcategory->bind_result($id_category, $title_category);
    while ($stmtcategory->fetch()) {    
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_one_more_news,cover_page,title,description,detail,url,date_post FROM one_more_news WHERE id_category=? order by id_one_more_news ASC LIMIT 2");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id_category);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
            echo '<div class="date-text">
                <h4>'.$title_category.'</h4>
                <ul>';
            $stmt->bind_result($id_one_more_news, $cover_page, $title, $description, $detail, $url, $date_post);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';
            }

            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "There is no news";
}
```